# Notification center can't recieve a notif

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, nsnotificationcenter

I've button inside `Collection View Cell` Whenever a person clicks that button, I want to register a notif, create variable `name` and set its value to the cell's property `nameLabel`, after that I want to send that notification to my second `Collection View` and set that `Collection View`'s cell `nameLabel`.text to `name` string which I sent from first `Collection View`

if you need any addition code let me know in the comments

```swift
extension Notification.Name {
    static let AddToFavorites = Notification.Name("add_to_favorites")
}
```

```swift
// button inside first collection view cell
    @IBAction func likeButoon(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Button works fine")
        let name = self.nameLabel.text    // first collection view cell's property nameLabel
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .AddToFavorites, object: name)
    }
```

```swift
// second collection view controller
    var string1:String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notificationRecieved), name: .AddToFavorites, object: nil)
    }
    @objc func notificationRecieved(notification: Notification){
        guard let name = notification.object as? String else {
            return
        }
        string1 = name
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionViewFavorites.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "favoritesCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCellFavorites
        cell?.nameLabel.text = string1        // Second collection view cell's property nameLabel
        return cell!
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refresh

```
string1 = name
collectionView.reloadData()
```